# I want to show gif image show on screen even when app is closed

Tags: android, service, android-service, java-threads, android-thread

With a mouse click, you implement two things:

- Sound is playing
- The GIF image is showing

I'm trying to show the GIF on the screen even when I close the app I'm using the services but because the sound keeps playing while the GIF image appears, I can not find the solution.

**TheService.java (CODE)**

```
package gallery.suitapps.catwalking;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;

public class TheService extends Service  {

    final class MyThreadClass implements Runnable{
        int service_id;
        MyThreadClass(int service_id){
            this.service_id=service_id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }

    SoundPool soundPool = null;
    private int[] f10685s;


    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    public MediaPlayer player;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Starts" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sound2);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();

        MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_gif);

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Stops" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        player.stop();
        MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java (CODE)**

```
package gallery.suitapps.catwalking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static GifImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.catgif);
    }

    public void startService (View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TheService.class);
        startService(intent);

       // imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_gif);

    }

    public void stopService (View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TheService.class);
        stopService(intent);

    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Start Service"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.134"
        android:onClick="startService"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Stop Service"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.362"
        android:onClick="stopService"/>

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/catgif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: check my answer , let me know if there it works or not

Comment: Yes it works, but not exactly what i want, it float the whole app screen on the screen of the mobile, while i just want the GIF to float over the screen.

Comment: okay, what part of screen of you want to show it ?

Comment: check my update in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to your requirement you need to implement **system window
>   alert** in service class to show image in background when the app is
>   closed

This is the solution for your requirement.

In `manifest` add this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Then in your launcher `activity` or any base activity add these permissions

```
 private static final int CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION = 2084;
```

In `onCreate()` add this

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
            //finish();
        }
```

Handle the request permission

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
            } else {
               // do stuff here 
            }
        }
    }
```

and do this in `service` class check the link below and do your stuff respectively

```
   https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064
```

where `image_layout`. xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/catgif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **Update**:- You can make changed in image_layout file to show your GIF any size and gravity in the screen
>   You can make changes with

```
android:layout_width="any_size"
    android:layout_height="any_size"
```